# LWC Base Datatable component Row Stripes

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to use the base [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component. However, I do not see a  way to implement the `slds-table_striped` CSS class as outlined in the Lighting Design System component blueprint (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#Striped-rows).

Is the only way to implement this is to re-create the datatable from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SLDS striped row class to datatable base component:

```html
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={accounts}
    columns={columns}
    class="slds-table_striped"
>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Output:

[image]

---

Only problem is with odd row, when selected they will have same color as unselected even rows:
[image]

Comment: Ah interesting, I would have thought the CSS class would have only been applied to the outer LWC component in the raw HTML `<lightning-datatable class="slds-table_striped">` and not to the actual HTML `<table>` element that needs the class

Comment: wow thanks @Raul should have just tried it from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately looks like you're out of luck. There are no documented attributes that would enable the striping so it'll only be available if you rebuild the component using the slds base component.